# Do we have to graduate to get a site design?

Tags: discussion

Is graduation a prerequisite for a nice design? I ask because a prettier site could help to attract more people. Also, it would just be nice to look at for the rest of us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically only graduated sites have designs, however there have been some exceptions (UX.SE). But even those exceptions are typically very close to graduation.

I'd say its a safe bet that we will not get a design until we are a month or less away from graduating.